# Asp.net inserting checked attribute on <asp:CheckBox>

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a  inside a FormView, that I use to Bind to a model only to Update in the database.

The problem happens when the flag is True in the database.

The asp.net inserts a checked attribute on the html input tag, and the value, when i post the form, is always true.

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFlag" Enabled="true" Checked='<%# Bind("flag") %>'
                                    runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:CheckBox>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input name="ctl00$cpConteudoPagina$formViewUser$chkFlag" id="cpConteudoPagina_formViewUsuario_chkPVE" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked">
```

All other controls on the page works fine.

Does somebody know why asp.net insert the checked attribute?

Comment: You can try setting up in the onDatabound event as well.(instead of binding it on the aspx page)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code to assign the `Checked`-state:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkFlag" Enabled="true" 
    Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("flag")) %>' /> %>'
    runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:CheckBox>
```